# How can you execute python terminal command using a Windows Batch script?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

So using Windows batch scripting I know we can open the python interpreter as follows and execute a python script:

```
c:\python27\python.exe c:\documents\python_script.py
```

In turn, I know it is possible to just open the python interpreter just by typing:

```
c:\python27\python.exe
```

However, using a batch script is it possible to "communicate" with the python interpreter and send it commands to execute ie:

```
c:\python27\python.exe import os
```

and then to exit from the interpreter as such:

```
c:\python27\python.exe exit()
```

Any insight would be kindly appreciated.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use -c option

```
c:\python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print sys.version"
```